# RDP Session without username & password prompt

Tags: rdp, image, thin-client

Iam currently working on a new image with thinstation for our terminal pcs. I want them to connect to our rds with the known windows login screen but that isnt the case. When I start the image, my clients receive a prompt from freerdp to enter their username and password and only after entering them they are connected to the terminal server. Ive tried to disable nla with several commands like --sec-nla; -sec-nla etc but nothing is helping to resolve the issue. Is there another way or config lines I have to add to get it working?

Best regards

Marie

Comment: disabling NLA is a really bad idea. You'll open your "door" to anyone having access to your internal network... Your description sounds like you trying to disable it at the freerdp client -  you would have to disable it on your RDS host server of course. Please share additional details (what OS, etc)

Comment: @Martin well it was just a try to test if its working without it. I dont really want to disable it. We already have clients who are directly connecting to the server but the config is lost. I just want them to connect to our server without putting the credentials beforehand in the freerdp prompt. our users should be able to log in directly via the windows login. we are using a windows 2019 server and for clients thinstation.